# Loops with grep script

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm asking this as a new question because people didn't seem to understand my original question.

I can figure out how to find if a word starts with a capital and is followed by 9 letters with the code:

```
echo "word" | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
```

So that's part 1 of what I'm supposed to do. My actual script is supposed to loop through each word in a text file that is given as the first and only argument, then check if any of those words start with a capital and are 9 letters long.

I've tried:

```
cat textfile | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
```

and

```
while read p
do echo $p | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}' 
done < $1
```

to no avail.

Although:

```
cat randomtext.txt
```

outputs:

```
The loud Brown Cow jumped over the White Moon. November October tesTer Abcdefgh Abcdefgha
```

so it's correctly outputting all the words in the file randomtext.txt

then why wouldn't

```
cat randomtext.txt | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
```

work?

Comment: `cat | grep` is useless, see http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat (`grep` can access files directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the anchor. Your pattern starts with `^` which matches the beginning of a line, but the word you want to get returned is in the middle of a line. You can replace it with `\b` to match at a word boundary.

Comment: yes, that's why I use `printf` to split each words on a newline.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. Can you explain what \b does? I've never encountered it.

Answer (score 1):

The words are all one after the other, but your `grep` expression refers to a *whole row*.

You ought to split the file into words:

```
sed -e 's/\s*\b\s*/\n/g' < file.txt | grep ...
```

Or maybe better, since you're only interested in alphanumeric sequences,

```
sed -e 's/\W\W*/\n/g' < file.txt | grep -E '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}$'
```

The $ (end of line) being made necessary because otherwise 'Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' would match.

(I had modified {8} in {9} because you specified "and is followed by *9* letters", but then I saw you also state "and are 9 letters long")

By the way, if you use {8} and -o, you might be led into thinking a match is there where it isn't. "-o" means "only print the part matching my pattern".

So if you fed "Supercalifragilistic" to "^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}", *it would accept it as a match* and print "Supercali". This is not what I think you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
$ cat file.txt
The loud Brown Cow jumped over the White Moon. November October tesTer Abcdefgh Abcdefgha
$ printf '%s\n' $(<file.txt) | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}$' 
Abcdefgha
```

If you want to work on the same source line, you need to remove the `^` character (means the beginning of the line) :

```
grep -Eo '\b[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}\b' file.txt
```

(added `\b` like choroba explains)

Comment: Probably it doesn't matter so much, but this way you're limited to $( getconf ARG_MAX ) characters in the file. Also, eleven-characters words are accepted due to the missing $.

Comment: ...and added `$` for the first solution.

Comment: @Iserni, you have mistaken my command behaviour, there's no limitation of ARG_MAX like you said here, see http://pastie.org/5100411

Comment: If you want to trigger the error you expected, try doing `grep -Eo $(<file.txt) file.txt> /dev/null`

Comment: you're right; it's shell dependant. If you use the internal `printf` (e.g. bash), it works; if it falls through `/usr/bin/printf`, it fails. I *still* think it's a bit risky, and I'd rather cutting with `sed`, but hey, TMTOWTDI :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you cat the whole line is fed to grep at once. You should split the words before feeding to grep.

You could try:

```
cat randomtext | awk '{ for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) {print $i } }' | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][a-z]{8}'
```

Comment: `cat | awk` is useless, `awk` can do it himself. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat

Comment: @sputnick I think it is quite useful that awk can react to stdin. Presumably you'd want the command to work with other sources than the example randomtext. But thanks for the award anyway!